# how to extract the required value from the url in C#

Tags: c#, query-string

I need to extract the value from the current url. 
For example if my url is

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
```

I need the result stored in an array splitted with respect to "/".

my array should contain [questions,ask]

Comment: Did you try string `Split` method ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) class:

```
var uri = new Uri("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask");
```

Now look at the [`uri.Segments`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.segments) property which represents a string array containing what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.Split` function.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448.aspx